# Lazy loading and SEO after deprecated escape fragments

Tags: seo, lazyloading

So, recently, I'm searching about lazy loading and how to approach to it in best way to be SEO friendly. So, here's my problem / doubt.

Goal is to save bandwidth on visitors, and to optimize performance of site to the max. So.... what I know and what I've researched is this:

- Solution with `noscript` isn't good at all because if user has 
  JavaScript disabled, then he / she could see the pictures.
- Image sitemaps are only good for putting meta tags and more
  informations about pictures. So... that means that **SITEMAP** is
  out.
- Escape fragmets was solution that I was going for, but... that solution is deprecated.

basically, I don't have any idea how to do lazy loading in a proper, SEO friendly way. Should I do something additional, or basically should I do nothing and let site to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have traditional pages for indexing and then using script divert real users to the lazy loading version. Those with no script end up on the traditional page so get what they were searching for too but this should be at levels you can cope with.

Comment: Would this not be penalised as cloaking?

Comment: Only if you drastically change the content

Comment: Not even if you change the content. It's only cloaking if you show Googlebot different things than actual users. As long as Googlebot with js sees the same as users with js, and Googlebot without sees the same as users without js, it's not cloaking.